# Lotus script debugging(breakpoint)

Tags: debugging, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a html link which calls an agent (8.5.3 domino). I want to debug the agent, but I am not able to set breakpoints(F9 does not work). Also I have started the debugger(tools->Debug LotusScript). so I have two questions:

1-Why I cannot set breakpoints?.

2-Since I have no breakpoints the control should have come to the first line of code. But this does not happen.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want to debug the agent when it is called from html link. The agent runs in this case on server. So, instead of debugging code on client side you have to use **remote debugging**. Here is a description how to do this: [Using the Remote Debugger](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_USING_THE_REMOTE_DEBUGGER.html&lang=de).

It might be easier to start and debug your agent from Notes Client if you can simulate the same conditions like agent is called on server. In this case "Tools->Debug LotusScript" will work. You'll set the breakpoints when debugger stops at first line of code.